# Why is my insertion into STL list running slow?

Tags: c++, list, stl

I'm trying to implement an undirected graph using adjacency list. I used the following code:

```
int v,e;
scanf("%d%d",&v,&e);
list<int> graph[3000];
for(int i=0;i<e;i++){
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    graph[a].push_back(b);
    graph[b].push_back(a);
}
```

To  test the running time of my code I created an input file with 3000 vertices and all possible edges. It took 2.2 seconds to run. I tried to optimise by changing it to a two dimensional array as follows

```
int graph[3000][3000];

for(int i=0;i<e;i++){
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    graph[a][p[a]]=b;
    graph[b][p[b]]=a;
    p[a]++;
    p[b]++;
}
```

where 'p' is of size 3000 initalised with all zeros. This code ran in just 0.35 seconds for the same input file. I'm  using gcc-4.3.2 compiler. I know insertion at the end of a list can be done in constant time then why is the first code running slow? Is there a chance of optimising the linked list implementation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Constant time can involve a large constant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Avoid `std::list`. That's a doubly linked list, which is very cache unfriendly (the nodes are randomly distributed in memory) and involves a large overhead (2 pointers per element). So every time you append something, the list allocates `2*sizeof(void*)+sizeof(int)` bytes and additionally some memory management overhead of `operator new`.

Later in the algorithm, when you will iterate over the values, you literally jump all over the whole memory, which is further slow.

The 2d array doesn't have this problem, but it does waste some memory.

I usually represent an adjacency list as a vector of vectors.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > graph;
```

Note that a vector can also `push_back` values in `O(1)` (as well as a `std::deque`, which can append even faster but is slower when traversing). If the graph is expected to be dense, then an adjacency matrix may be a better choice.

Comment: `vector::push_back` is amortized O(1). You still want to use `reserve` or `resize` if you know the size beforehand (you can do similar things with `list`) Or `std::array` for fixed-size.

Answer (score 6):

Insertion into a list requires allocating a new node. So when you're doing your 6000 push-backs, you have to do 6000 memory allocations. In the array case, you don't have to do any allocations at all, so that's a lot faster. That's the full difference.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answers here, implement a linked list class yourself, and you will find out why it is slow.

There are things that can be done such as implementing a list containing a capacity value, a size value and a pointer that points to the first node in the actual list. That pointer is actually a dynamic array, and when size==capacity, the array is resized and the capacity increased by some factor (e.g. 10).

The drawback is that it is limited to 2^(sizeof capacity * CHAR_BIT) - 1 elements whereas just allocating nodes each time involves longer insertion times with the benefit of a theoretically unlimited amount of nodes. You'd most likely run out of memory before maxing out the capacity of the faster list implementation, but there is no guarantee of that, not to mention resizing the list usually involves making a copy of it, so that capacity maximum suddenly has a much smaller limit on it anyway.

Linked lists are generally slow. They have their uses, but if you need fast run times, find a better implementation, use a different container such as std::vector, or create a solution yourself, though honestly the standard containers do pretty well.